# Как сделать так чтобы мой дискорд бот на пайтоне повторял сообщения но не повторял их бесконечно?

Tags: python, discord, бот

я сделал так чтобы бот повторял сообщения. но он повторяет их бесконечно.
вот отрывок из кода:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
       await message.reply(message.content)
```

Comment: Надеюсь, строка с `await` стоит с отступами? Просто если код у Вас такой же, какой он в вопросе, то иногда код может работать довольно плохо, если вообще он запустится

Answer (score -1):

Добавьте в код

```
if message.author == bot.user:
  return
```